# sub string for non English languages

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, character-encoding, substring

I want to remove last three characters from a string if it contains specific keywords.
It is working for me but when I have other language than English like Russian or Spanish then my query is not working. Here is my query:

```
SELECT case when 'Época Cosméticos_T2' like '%\_T_' 
then  substring(trim('Época Cosméticos_T2'),1,length(trim('Época Cosméticos_T2'))-3)
else 'Época Cosméticos_T2' end test
```

Result:

```
Época Cosméticos_T
```

If I remove characters `É` and `é` then query will work. How can I make my query work with these characters as well.

Comment: Hint: language doesn't matter—encoding (which you only mention in question tags) does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `CHAR_LENGTH()` function in place of `LENGTH()` function.

The `LENGTH()` function reports length in bytes rather than characters.

The `CHAR_LENGTH()` reports length in characters; the `SUBSTRING()` function also operates on characters.

If all of the characters in a string are a single byte, then LENGTH() and CHAR_LENGTH() return the same value. The differences become apparent with multibyte characters:

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH('Época Cosméticos_T2') AS _char_length
     , LENGTH('Época Cosméticos_T2') AS _length

_char_length  _length  
------------  -------
          19       21
```